# Problem using function useEffect() in React Hooks

Tags: reactjs

I have a little problem. I searched all over the internet and I can't find an answer. I'm trying to use function useEffect(), but unfortunately, I can`t.
I have to say that I imported useEffect via import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: when you say you can't, are you getting an error message? if so, what does it say?

Answer (score 1):

First to use useEffect hook you need to use it within function component **and** only at the top level of function like this

```
function SomeComponent() {

    // >> HERE << you should use it within this area

    return (
        // some JSX 
    )
}
```

And what this hook can do you can read more at [React useEffect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) from official site

---

This section I will explain how to use it in the way I understand. There are 3 way to use this hook
**First:** Run only on the first time component rendered

```
function SomeComponent() {

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("This will run once when rendered!")
    }, []) // << Leave this list blank

    return (
        // some JSX 
    )
}
```

**Second:** Run every time when something in watching list is updated

```
function SomeComponent() {

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("This will run when a or b or c has updated!")
    }, [a, b, c]) // << This is watching list

    return (
        // some JSX 
    )
}
```

**Third:** Run when this component re-rendered (also the first time rendered)

```
function SomeComponent() {

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("This will run when I first rendered and every time I re-rendered!")
    }) // << Remove the list completely

    return (
        // some JSX 
    )
}
```

---

This is my understanding sorry if I say something wrong feel free to correct me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem was the version of React. I made an update to version 16.18.1 and it`s working.